# Qooxdoo/JSON Array undefined value

Tags: arrays, json, qooxdoo

I'm working in order to connect my client to my server (node.js). I use this code :

var storeEmployees = new qx.data.store.Json("Load/Infos");

```
        qx.event.Registration.addListener(storeEmployees, "loaded", function(){
            var model = this.getModel();

            console.log(model.getRecords());
            console.log(model.getTotal());
            console.log(model.getStatus());
        }, storeEmployees);
```

My server send this value :

```
{records: ["bonjour", "aurevoir"], total:2, status:"success"}
```

however the `"console.log(model.getRecords())"` write on the console :

```
Object[undefined, undefined]
```

Instead of

```
Object["bonjour","aurevoir"]
```

Values for `"getTotal"` and `"getStatus"` are good. The problem is only for the array (simple array and complexe array).

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The store marshals the data to model objects. This means that you are dealing with qx.data.Array here which unfortunately can not be accessed vie brackets notation (e.g. Data[0]). But this is what the console does. For debugging and logging you can access the plain array with the .toArray() method which then will show the results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the case of the official demo-browser.data.JsonToList, we can see that they use this Json file : (http://demo.qooxdoo.org/4.1/demobrowser/resource/demobrowser/demo/data/list.json). This file also uses an array with brackets and that works. However, I will investigate your answers in order to better understand.

Comment: Ok that works with toArray(). Thanks for your answer ! you are right. The problem is not in the JSON but in the console when I tried to write the value of the array. Thanks !